# PDFMerger class redeclare issue

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I have to merge two PDF files - PDF, created by TCPDF and existing file. I've tried to use [`PDFMerger` library](http://pdfmerger.codeplex.com/) for that, but simple object creation

```php
    $merger = new PDFMerger;
```

throws that `Fatal error`:

```php
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class FPDF in /home/roman/www/comfin/plugins/wiPDFMergerPlugin/lib/PDFMerger/fpdi/fpdi2tcpdf_bridge.php on line 171
```

Maybe someone knows how can I fix that or can advise another way to merge two PDFs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know how `fpdi2tcpdf_bridge` should work - `class redeclare` problem appears. But for my needs quick fix was just not using it.

```php
    //    require_once('fpdi2tcpdf_bridge.php');
```

in `fpdi.php`.